# Updating old mpi_wrapper subroutines

Tags: fortran, mpi

I am working on some old fortran 90 code which uses wrapper subroutines for mpi commands. The subs have to take in data objects of the same type but of differing rank (0, 1 and 2). Below is given a snippet for integer variables.

With the current code I get the following error message, when compiling with GCC and FLAGS `-Wimplicit-interface -Werror`:

```
 1607 |                call mpi_int_ssend (new_loc(1, i), 2, MPI_INTEGER, &
      |                                   1
Error: Element of assumed-shape or pointer array passed to array dummy argument ‘buf’ at (1)
```

```
  ! -> PASSING SCALAR (ERROR GENERATED)
  call mpi_int_ssend ( &
    & new_loc(1, i), &
    & 2, &
    & MPI_INTEGER, & 
    & child(2, j, i), &
    & child(1,j,i), &
    & MPI_COMM_WORLD, & 
    & ierr &
    & )
.
.
.
  ! -> PASSING VECTOR (NO ERROR)
  call mpi_int_ssend (&
    & lreflevel (1 : lnblocks), &
    & lnblocks, & 
    & MPI_INTEGER, & 
    & 0, &
    & 2, & 
    & MPI_COMM_WORLD, &
    & ierr &
    & )
.
.
.
  ! -> PASSING MATRIX (NO ERROR)
  call mpi_int_ssend ( &
    & mort_no (:, 1 : lnblocks), & 
    & size (mort_no, 1) * lnblocks, & 
    & MPI_INTEGER, & 
    & 0, &
    & 1, & 
    & MPI_COMM_WORLD, &
    & ierr &
    & )
.
.
.
  ! -> CALLED SUBROUTINE 
  subroutine mpi_int_ssend (buf, count, datatype, dest, tag, comm, ierror)
    use mpi
    integer :: buf(*)
    integer :: count, datatype, dest, tag, comm, ierror

    call mpi_ssend(buf, count, datatype, dest, tag, comm, ierror)

    return
  end subroutine mpi_int_ssend
```

As using assumed-size dummy arguments (`integer :: buf(*)`) is not recommended, I have started to refactor the subroutines using modules and generic interfaces with module procedures (snippet below). This solves the problem with the error messages during compilation.

```
  interface mpi_int_ssend

    module procedure mpi_int_ssend_scalar
    module procedure mpi_int_ssend_vector
    module procedure mpi_int_ssend_matrix

  end interface mpi_int_ssend
.
.
.

  subroutine mpi_int_ssend_scalar (buf, count, datatype, dest, tag, comm, ierror)
    use mpi
    integer :: buf
    integer :: count, datatype, dest, tag, comm, ierror

    call mpi_ssend(buf, count, datatype, dest, tag, comm, ierror)

    return
  end subroutine mpi_int_ssend_scalar


  subroutine mpi_int_ssend_vector(buf, count, datatype, dest, tag, comm, ierror)
    use mpi
    integer, dimension (:) :: buf
    integer :: count, datatype, dest, tag, comm, ierror

    call mpi_ssend(buf, count, datatype, dest, tag, comm, ierror)

    return
  end subroutine mpi_int_ssend_vector


  subroutine mpi_int_ssend_matrix(buf, count, datatype, dest, tag, comm, ierror)
    use mpi
    integer, dimension (:, :) :: buf
    integer :: count, datatype, dest, tag, comm, ierror

    call mpi_ssend(buf, count, datatype, dest, tag, comm, ierror)

    return
  end subroutine mpi_int_ssend_matrix
```

**As I have little experience in coding with MPI, I wanted to ask whether the change from assumed-size to assumed-shape will impact the execution of the standard MPI_SSEND command in this example?**

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use the Fortran 2008 MPI bindings?

Comment: @francescalus I can't tell. The original files (about 100) still used `include 'mpif.h'`, which I changed to `use mpi`. If I wanted to, I could update to `use mpi_f08` with a simple find and replace. I didn't go for it because I don't know whether I would have to update all existing MPI commands to Fortran 2008 syntax as well.

Comment: It's true that not all procedures in `mpi` (and `mpif.h`) are identical to the corresponding one in `mpi_f08`. But consider what problem those in-house wrappers are trying to solve. If you've identified a weakness in the wrapping solution, it's time to look at how to solve that problem with the tools you have now, not how to solve a 40-year-old problem with 30-year-old tools.

Comment: @francescalus I get your point. However, my objective is to run simulations and obtain scientific results using the code I have and not to update it to the current standard, i.e. my priority is to get it running. That said, I thought of it as being necessary to at least update to `use mpi`, which is relatively simple to do, and to provide explicit interfaces through the use of `interface blocks`.

Comment: Unless you want to use compiler specific pragmas (ignore_tkr or similar), using the mpi_f08 is likely easier.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I don't get how changing to mpi_f08 would help in my case. Can you elaborate? Besides, the discussion has drifted away from the original question on whether changing from assumed-size to assumed-shape has any impact on MPI_SSEND in the example above.

Comment: The question about the change to assumed-shape from assumed-size is moot. [MPI F2008 binding for `mpi_ssend`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v3.1/man3/MPI_Ssend.3.php#toc4) already provides an explicit interface accepting a buffer of any type and any rank. Unless you can explain why you want to ignore this and roll your own, horribly ummaintainable, wrappers with generics, it's hard for anyone else to empathise with your goals.

Comment: That's all to say, it's laudable that you want to ensure explicit interfaces are available for your calls. But these _already exist as part of the MPI standard_.

Comment: @francescalus I assume you are referring to the calls to MPI commands. What I mean is explicit interfaces for user-defined subroutines written in Fortran, some of which use MPI and others that do not. But I think I understand your argument: Why use deprecated wrappers for MPI commands, when the MPI commands can be integrated directly into the code. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes. All those specific procedures under the generic `mpi_int_ssend` are very thin wrappers which just call `mpi_ssend`. So instead of working out which generic to call (based on type) then have that generic resolve to a particular specific (based on rank), which then simply calls `mpi_ssend`: just directly call `mpi_ssend`.

Comment: For context: this particular issue with F90 being entirely incapable of supporting "choice arguments" is why the implicit interface hack is used, even though illegal. Trying to provide legal generics to avoid such hacks is one way, but then F2008 was developed and the C interoperability facility of Fortran was extended so that MPI can be used in a conforming way.

Comment: @francescalus Yes, that makes a lot of sense indeed. Thank you very much for the tip; I appreciate it. Also the context you have provided makes a lot of sense.
I must admit that I do not know the best way to make my code run (most code dates back to 1999, last major update was in 2007). I just settled on the brute force approach to invest a couple of weeks to upgrade the most pressing parts. Maybe you can provide some insight regarding this issue? It is 100% Fortran 90, all procedures are in separate files and **not** in modules, some explicit interfaces are provided and only MPIF.H is used.

Comment: note `use mpi_f08` requires some Fortran 2008 support from your compiler (from a pragmatic point of view, you won't be able to use `gfortran` that comes in CentOS 7 like distros, but gfortran >= 4.9.